# Visual Studio 2013 and two step authentication crashes?

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-2013

I've enabled two step authentication on my Windows Live account. I then load Visual Studio 2013 and go to open an application (it uses TFS and I sign in to my account to access it).

I get a 'this application is not responding' message.

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.30501.0, time
>   stamp: 0x5361f453 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.3.9600.17055, time stamp: 0x532943a3 Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x00011d4d Faulting process ID: 0x2d4c Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01cf8fec4ff9c2b7 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll Report ID:
>   a096268c-fbdf-11e3-bfef-f46d049726f3 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

I've tried rebooting, signing out of my account within VS and signing back in.

As soon as I disable two step authentication then the problem goes away.

If I go to file - new project, it creates a new project. Just as it finished loading the new project I get the same error.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Thanks!